# Ошибка при попытке приведения double к string

Tags: c#, строки, double

У меня есть метод типа `string`, который принимает два аргумента: `string` и `double`.

На выходе мне нужно выдать, насколько я понимаю, оба аргумента в `string`.

Но возникает ошибка: компилятор не может перевести `double` в `string`. Пробовал разные варианты: cast `(string)` перед `double` переменной, `double.ToString`, `ConvertToString` и т.д.

Какой метод нужно использовать?

Сам код:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyMethod("Hello", 11.0));
    }

    private static string MyMethod(string word, double num)

    {
        num = Math.Round(num);
        string snum = num.ToString();
        return MyMethod(word, num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит `на выходе мне нужно выдать насколько я понимаю оба аргумента в strin`? Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Это не подходит: `double initialValue = 0.6822871999174;
      string valueString = initialValue.ToString("R");`?

Comment: На выходе может быть только  один аргумент (точнее сказать, возвращаемое значение). Или массив. Покажите код, что Вы пытаетесь вернуть. Может проблема в попытке вернуть 2 значения?

Comment: `"насколько я понимаю"` что это ?пишите код и не знаете что от вас требуется?

Comment: Вот сам код : class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MyMethod("Hello", 11.0));
            
        }


        private static string MyMethod (string word, double num)
        {

            
            

           return MyMethod(word, num) ;
            
           
        }
    }

Comment: Метод `MyMethod` очень смахивает на бесконечную рекурсию. Каков смысл этого метода?

Comment: По задаче мне нужно округлить double до целого числа, я использовал num = Math.Round(num); Но толку нет.

Comment: @Has, _Но толку нет_ - почему ты думаешь, что толку нет? в предоставленном коде ты **нигде** не приводишь double к строке

Comment: А аргумент `word` зачем здесь? И что и почему всё-таки должен возвращать метод `MyMethod`?

Comment: @Regent, подозреваю он должен был возвращать `$"{word} {Math.Round(num)}"`

Comment: @Grundy да, тоже об этом подумывал. Но учитывая оформление вопроса и код, не удивлюсь, если на самом деле нужно собрать ракету и улететь на Луну.

Comment: Привел double к строке все равно ошибка при запуске

Comment: @Has, дай угадаю: Stack overflow?

Comment: как ты думаешь, что происходит, когда ты пишешь внутри функции `MyMethod` -> `return MyMethod(word, num);`?

Comment: Что должно быть на выходе? Округленное число в строковом виде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static string MyMethod(string word, double num)

{
    num = Math.Round(num);
    string snum = num.ToString();
    return word + " " + snum;


}
```

Вы это хотели получить?
ЗЫ: Сложение строк - не лучший вариант с точки зрения производительности,  но наиболее понятный начинающему

Что же касается Вашего вопроса, заданного у комментариях:
У Вас в определении метода указано, что он возвращает строку : `private static string MyMethod` ... То есть, на выходе из метода Вы хотите получить строку.
  `return word + " " + snum;` означает: вернуть  строку состоящую из word, пробела и  snum. Что и требуется.

```
return MyMethod(word, num);
```

означает совершенно другое. Это означает примерно следующее: перед выходом из метода еще раз вызвать метод MyMethod с параметрами word b num, и вернуть результат отработки этого метода. Поэтому у Вас в последней строке не происходит выхода из метода, а вызывается еще один экземпляр метода (это называется рекурсия). И так до бесконечности. Но в случае с компьютером, бесконечность ограничивается объемом свободной памяти. И как только Вы превышаете этот объем программа аварийно завершается и сообщает Вам об этом исключением StackOwerflow.

Comment: в данном случае сложение не влияет на производительность

Comment: Большое спасибо, но почему нельзя возврщать в таком виде :       return MyMethod(word, num);                                                                             Ведь это более логично

Comment: Добавлю в ответ через пару минут